# Wordpress get current site's db tables

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm using multisite function in my wordpress and my database is kinda messed up (3 sites):

```
wp_posts
wp_2_posts
wp_3_posts
wp_comments
wp_2_comments
...
```

I am creating plugin which plays with database. And I need it to know which table it should take: for example, first site has to play with wp_posts, second site - with wp_2_posts and so on. Is there any variables or functions to make it happen?

If I write in query, for example `select * from wp_posts` this plugin will take wp_posts table in every site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE` constant, which retrieve current blog id. And to get the table prefix of current blog e.g: `wp_BLOGID_` you can use `$wpdb` method `get_blog_prefix()`.

```
$blog_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix(BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE); // wp_posts or wp_2_posts so on..
```

Then you can use your query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM " . $blog_prefix . "posts"
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make use of the [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class (check the link) there you'll find a lot of info about manipulating the database.

The class gets automatically the current site database.

To get data from the database without have to hardcode the table names, you have to:

```php
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    //This is the name of the post table
    echo $wpdb->posts 

    $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");

?>
```

Sorry for bad english.